# Expectation of a weighted random walk given that it's positive

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value

Let $m\in \mathbb R^d$ such that $||m||_2=1$.

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_d$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $$X_i=\begin{cases}1 & \mbox{w.p. $1/2$} \\ -1&\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Define $Y=\sum_{i=1}^d X_i\cdot m_i$.

I'm looking to compute $\mathbb E[Y | Y \ge 0]$, as a function of $m$. Does this have a simple formula or do we have to sum over all $2^d$ options for the $X_i$'s?

(I'm looking to implement this, so summing over all options would not be feasible).

Comment: You ask "Does this have a simple formula or do we have to sum over all $2^d$ options for the $X_i$'s?"  Isn't there another alternative?  Namely, it could be that there is no simple formula, but there is an efficient algorithm, say, an algorithm that given $m$ computes the expectation in time polynomial in $d$.  Perhaps you could ask whether the problem "given $m$, compute the expectation" has a polynomial time algorithm, or whether it is NP-hard.  Phrased in that way, it would be an appropriate question for cstheory.stackexchange.com .

Comment: FWIW, if you replace the assumption that $||m||_2=1$ by an assumption that each $m_i$ is an integer, then there is a dynamic-programming algorithm that runs in time polynomial in $d$ and $\max_i |m_i|$.  The algorithm is similar to, for example, the standard algorithm for the Subset Sum problem.

Comment: @NealYoung Is there any obvious reduction from $\textsf{Subset-Sum}$ or (the counting version) $\textsf{Knapsack}$? I couldn't see any, but the problems seem related.

Comment: (i) Off the top of my head I don't see a reduction from any NP-hard problem to your problem, but I wouldn't rule it out.  (ii) Another option may be to compute an approximate answer of some form quickly.  E.g. maybe there is an algorithm that outputs an estimate that differs from the true answer by at most an additive $\epsilon \max_i |m_i|$, in time polynomial in $d$ and $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks @NealYoung and Clement for the comments. If this question will be left unanswered I will try reposting it to cstheory.